# How to update/ set database child text with onclicklistener from within recyclerview?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

So I'm trying to set an onclicklistener update a database child from recycler view to a specific text but I'm a little stuck any help will be greatly appreciated

```
   public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        textView_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textView_decription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        textView_address =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
        textView_phone =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(phone);
        textView_Pickup =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(pickup);
        textView_Confirm =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(confirm);
        bconfirm = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bcomfirm);
        bpickup = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bpickup);


        bpickup.setOnClickListener(this);
        bconfirm.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    //new
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (View == bpickup){
            //set action
```

This is where I'm stuck at. I'm just not sure the code to set the action to update my database child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            textView_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            textView_decription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            textView_address =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            textView_phone =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(phone);
            textView_Pickup =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(pickup);
            textView_Confirm =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(confirm);
            bconfirm = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bcomfirm);
            bpickup = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bpickup);

            bpickup.setOnClickListener(this);
            bconfirm.setOnClickListener(this);
}


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (v.getId() == bpickup.getId()) {
                // set your actions
            }
             //here you can use else, if the first one didn't get call 
             //then the second one will be
            if(v.getId() == bconfirm.getId()){
                // set your actions
            }
        }
```

Comment: Awesome .. i do have one more question if i can ask

Comment: @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == bpickup.getId()) {
                //set action

                reference.child("pickup").setValue("Confirmed time");

            }
        }

Comment: what do I add to get the key the child is under? So when it sends to firebase it replaces the child value instead of adding a new child

Comment: String Id = "KHGJHAGDJGAUYA";                                      FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("your node");   
reference .child(Id).child("which key value you want to set").setValue("value");

Comment: I get that but I'm trying to set this up as where someone can click the button bpickup then it will overwrite the existing child pickup in the database.. kinds like adding a comment to a post .. would I need to get the key of that specific post then overwrite the child pickup value

Comment: Yes, you need to get that specific key then just overwrite the value.

Comment: Thats what im trying to do can i pull the key of the child and set the value at the same time ?

Comment: what do i need to add to pull the existing key the child is under then be able to use that key to update the value of the child

Comment: To achieve this, I made the user id as a node key and pulled data from it and also when updating something, I used that key to specify the node. But I really can't say this can help you or not. If you need the code, let me know.